# ¿Cómo sumar el valor de x variable a un campo en la db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una tabla `articles` y una `purchases`. cada vez que cargo un `purchase` quiero que me actualize el campo `stock` en mi tabla `articles`.

Cómo puedo sumar la variable `stock` + lo que ya tengo en el campo `stock` de x articulo?

Tengo esto:

**Model**

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :save_articles

  def articles=(value)
    @articles = value
  end

  private
  def save_articles
    if @articles.nil?

    else
      @articles.zip($stock, $price_cost).each do |article_id, stock, 
      price_cost|
      Purchasearticle.create(article_id: article_id, purchase_id: 
      self.id, stock: stock, price_cost: price_cost)
      unless Articleprovider.where("article_id = ?", article_id).nil?
      Articleprovider.update(price_cost: price_cost)
      Article.update(stock: Article.stock + stock)
   end
 end
end
end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationContorller
  ...
  def create
    @providers = Provider.all

    @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
    @purchase.articles = params[:articles]
    $stock = params[:stock]
    $price_cost = params[:price_cost]

    if @purchase.save
      redirect_to @purchase
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

**Migration**

```
`create_table "purchasearticles", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer "purchase_id"
   t.integer "article_id"
   t.decimal "stock", null: false
   t.decimal "price_cost", null: false
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end`
```

**Function**

`...
    var article = $(this).data("id")
    var article_name = $(this).data("name")
    var article_code = $(this).data("code")
    $('#articles_purchases').append("<tr><input type='hidden' name='articles[]' value='"+ article +"' id='articles_id'><td>"+ article_code +"</td><td id='name'>"+ article_name +"</td><td><input type='number' name='stock[]' placeholder='Stock...'></td><td><input type='number' step='0.01' name='price_cost[]' placeholder='Price cost...'></td><td><a href='#' id='delete_row' class='btn-flat waves-effect waves-light'><i class='material-icons right'>delete</i>delete</a></td></tr>");
    ...`

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Y lo que tienes funciona o no funciona? Si no funciona ¿arroja algún error o no? Si arroja algún error ¿cuál es? Por favor edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: __[mcve]__.

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver, parece ser que tienes una relación muchos a muchos  entre `Article` y `Purchase` a través del modelo `Purchasearticle`, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Si, así es.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución

**Purchase.rb**

```
after_create :update_articles_stock


def articles=(value)
  @articles = value
end

private
def update_articles_stock
  @articles.zip($stock).each do |article_id, stock|
    Article.where("id = ?", article_id).each do |article|
      Article.find(article_id).update(stock: article.stock.to_d + 
      stock.to_d)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes lograr utilizando algún *callback* de *ActiveRecord*<sup>1</sup>, en particular considero que `after_create` seria el adecuado. Lo que hace este *callback* es ejecutar un método después de crear un registro en el modelo.

Por ejemplo, asumiendo que un objeto `Purchase` pertenezca a un objeto `Article` (i.e. una compra involucra sólo un artículo), podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  after_create :update_stock

  private
  def update_stock
    article.update(stock: article.stock + stock)
  end
end
```

Donde `stock` es la columna que tiene el *stock* en la tabla `purchases` (i.e. modelo `Purchase`).

Con este código, cada vez que generes un nuevo registro en `purchases`, se ejecutará el método `update_stock`, el cual actualiza la columna `stock` del objeto `Article` relacionado.

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Otros posibles* callbacks *que podrías utilizar son `after_save` y `after_update`, dependiendo del objetivo específico que busques.*</sup>

Comment: line: Article.update(stock: Article.stock + stock) error: 
undefined method `stock' for #<Class:0x007fd4a36f1600>

Comment: @MatiasCarpintini. ¿Podrías mostrar la estructura (o migraciones) de las tablas `purchases` y `articles`?

Comment: `class AddPriceCostToArticleproviders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :articleproviders, :price_cost, :decimal, default: "0.00"
  end
end`

Comment: `unless Articleprovider.where("article_id = ?", article_id).nil?
          Articleprovider.update(price_cost: price_cost)
          Article.update(stock: Article.stock + stock)
        end`

Comment: @MatiasCarpintini. ¿Podrías agregarlo en tu pregunta? De esa forma será más claro el código. Además, veo que es la migración para agregar una columna, pero no muestra la estructura completa de las tablas; ¿podrías incluir en su lugar el archivo schema.rb? Ahí se muestra la estructura completa de tu BD.